# get employee detail by id in reactjs-redux

Tags: api, reactjs, redux

I am newb to reactjs

I want get employee detail which id is `3` when employee page load (`http://localhost:8080/employees/3`).

My Code:

***EmpPage.js***

```js
import React,{PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getEmp} from '../../actions/empActions';
import configureStore from '../../store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

class EmpPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    componentWillMount () {
        var id = this.props.params.id;
        store.dispatch(getEmp({'userId': id}));
    }

    render() {
        const emp = this.props.emp;
        console.log('emp================', emp); //issue: get blank object
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Emp Page...</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

EmpPage.propTypes = {
    emp: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.object
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        emp: state.emp
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EmpPage);
```

I want get employee detail, I am getting blank object

```js
render() {
        const emp = this.props.emp;
        console.log('emp================', emp); //issue: get blank object
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Emp Page...</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

API response is get successfully, when call `componentWillMount ()`, but state not set in mapStateToProps().

but when I have called dispatch `store.dispatch(getEmp({'userId': id}));` form index.js instated of `componentWillMount ()` then state `emp: state.emp` set successfully in `mapStateToProps`.

So, I want to get employee detail when page load and display it in html page.

Comment: What is the state inside mapStateToProps (`console.log(state)`)?

Comment: @HonzaHaering : get blank object

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're creating a new store and dispatching to it:

```
const store = configureStore();
```

...

```
store.dispatch(getEmp({'userId': id}));
```

Instead of hitting `store` directly, you should bind your action creators to the store provided from `<Provider>` by defining the `mapDispatchToProps` arg of `connect`.

EDIT: The relevant changes would look like:

```
componentWillMount () {
    var id = this.props.params.id;
    this.props.getEmp({'userId': id}));
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getEmp })(EmpPage);
```

Comment: you mean call `getEmp({'userId': id}`

Comment: you mean call `getEmp({'userId': id}` from mapDispatchToProps. if yes how to get id from URL in mapDispatchToProps function?

Comment: Thanks... its working....  Have you know any nice tutorial link for reactjs-redux where I will learn react-redux.